# Background worker and chart update

Tags: c#, .net, charts, backgroundworker, begininvoke

I am using a a background worker to read data values from a device and display in a chart.mI use BeginInvoke and update the values in the chart. The problem is that the values are getting updated in the chart with at least 2 - 3 seconds delay and is not real time. The speed of update in the chart also varies, at one instant the chart gets updated with all the previous values.

How do I make it real time? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest one of 2 options.

1) Make the chart itself a separate WPF form embedded withing the main UI and use Invoke rather than BeginInvoke to update the chart (this will freeze the chart UI when updating, but who cares)

2) Use a [DispatchTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) on the UI side to pull the data rather than having the processing push it to the UI...in my experience BeginInvoke never performs very well.

Comment: I cannot use Option one as I had trouble using it. I can try option 2.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have too many updates and it's congesting the message queue. The messages are likely going to arrive out of order. You can probably consolidate multiple updates into a single `BeginInvoke`. Alternatively, you can read all the values from the device and deliver only the latest value with `Invoke`. Invoke will ensure that it gets delivered before your next `Invoke`.

Comment: I cannot read all the values from the device at once. It is an user interactive system. Depending on user's feedback the device will send different values

Comment: read until the buffer is clear. in other words, until no more data is pending.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I refer as UI contention. The very nature of the BeginInvoke Async programming depends on the pull from the source and push it to UI. I suspect your BeginInvoke it taking more time here. I will try "DispatchTimer" or if you are using C# 4.0, try to use "Tasks".